# Finding points modulo Z^{n}

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the set $ M=\{ \lambda_{0}(e_{1}+...+e_{n})+\lambda_{1}e_{1}+...+\lambda_{n}e_{n}| \, \lambda_{0},...,\lambda_{n} \in \mathbb{R} $  with $|\lambda_{i}|<\frac{1}{2} \, \forall i\in \overline{0,n}\} $. Here the $ e_{i} $ are the elements of the canonical basis of $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $, $ n \geq 1 $.
Is it then possible to find $ 2^{n} $ points in $ M $ such that their coordinates differ by integers, i.e.  $x_{1},...,x_{2^{n}} $ distinct points in $ M $ such that $ x_{i}-x_{j} \in \mathbb{Z}^{n} \, \forall i,j \in \overline{1,2^{n}} $

For $ n=1 $, we can find such 2 distinct elements in $ M=\{\lambda_{0}e_{1}+\lambda_{1}e_{1}| |\lambda_{i}|<\frac{1}{2} \, \forall i \in \{1,2\}\} $. We can take $ x_{1}=(-\frac{1}{4}) \cdot 1+(-\frac{1}{4}) \cdot 1=-\frac{1}{2} $ and $ x_{2}=(\frac{1}{4}) \cdot 1+(\frac{1}{4}) \cdot 1=\frac{1}{2} $. Clearly $ x_{2}-x_{1}=1 \in \mathbb{Z} $.

For $ n \geq 2 $, I had an idea to choose the $ 2^{n} $ points as $ x=(\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon)(e_{1}+...+e_{n})+\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(k_{i},\varepsilon)e_{i} $ for $ \varepsilon $ small enough, where $ k_{i} \in \{0,1\} \, \forall i \in \overline{1,n} $ and $ f $ is a function such that $ f(1, \varepsilon)-f(0,\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{ 0 \} $ and $ |f(0,\varepsilon)|,|f(1,\varepsilon)| <\frac{1}{2} $.But unfortunately, there are no such examples since the conditions on the function $ f $ lead to a contradiction using the triangle inequality.

Also, for what I am working with, it would be enough to lessen the condition on the $ \lambda_{i} $, that is, to suppose that $ |\lambda_{i}| \leq \frac{1}{2}  \, \forall i \in \overline{0,n} $ and that for at least one $ i $, the inequality is strict.

Actually, for the case where we relax the condition on the $ \lambda_{i} $, it is easy to see that the $ 2^{n} $ points $ (\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon)(e_{1}+...+e_{n})+(\pm \frac{1}{2})e_{1}+...+(\pm \frac{1}{2})e_{n} $ satisfy the desired condition.

I don't know how to prove or disprove the fact that we can find $ 2^{n} $ such points in the restricted case, although I believe it shouldn't be possible for $ n>1 $.

Comment: By "differ by integers", do you mean $x,y \in M$ such that $x-y \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ ? or something else?

Comment: Can you do it for $n=1$? $n=2$?

Comment: I did it for n=1, but I don't know what to do for n greater than 1.